# Difference Between Two Methods When Switching Between ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When Switching between two view controllers, what's the difference between `addSubView` or using a navigation controller and using `pushViewController`?

In my app, I have a few set up screens in the beginning before a game calculator starts (which has a lot of view switching in between, and a lot of ViewControllers are reused).

In that case, should I set up a navigation controller in the AppDelegate or in the RootViewController, or just use `addSubView` in the first few set up screens and add a navigation controller where my calculator views start after the set up screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that with `addSubiview`, you add a view to another, which therefore will contain it. The navigation controller actually manages a stack of VC, in which the next view isn't included in the previous.

Another diference is about parameters, `addSubview` will accept a view as argument, while the other will accept a view controller.

Typically, a navigation controller is used when displaying hierarchical content (in a table view most of the time), that allow the user to go deeper in details, or getting back to previous levels.

Comment: So to push view controllers, I will have to use a navigation controller? Is it possible to sort of, clear the stack and remove the back button in navigation controllers? Furthermore, is it better to declare a navigation controller in the `AppDelegate` or the `RootViewController`?

Comment: to push yes, because `UIView` doesn't declare such a method. I think what you want is possible, but don't forget my answer, it was initially intended to present hierachical content. You might have a look to [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yeah I've read it a lot and wrote many navigation based bapps but I am confused about certain aspects of it. I am trying to look for an advanced Navigation Controller tutorial. Thank you

Comment: yes another good resource is the excelent [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple.